# Сложная if else конструкция

Tags: python, if

Не могу понять почему не срабатывает блок кода в ELSE,
подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело ?

```
competitor = r['offers'][0]['merchantName'] # беру из ответа API запроса
sku = 12345678 # беру из ответа API запроса
if competitor != self.StoreName:
                        
    logger.success("Товар: " + str(sku) + " - найден конкурент: " + competitor)
    competitor_price = int(r['offers'][0]['price']) # беру из ответа API запроса
    
    # Эти данные беру из MongoDB
    min_limit = self.mycol.find_one({"sku": sku})['min_limit']
    max_limit = self.mycol.find_one({"sku": sku})['max_limit']
    check_sku = self.mycol.find_one({"sku": sku})['sku']
    
    if check_sku == sku:
        
        if competitor_price < min_limit:
            logger.info("Цена конкурента ниже порога!")
            price = min_limit
            self.add_offer(sku, name, brand, price) #отправляю в функцию для сбора данных в XML файл

        elif competitor_price > max_limit:
            logger.info("Цена конкурента выше порога!")
            price = max_limit
            self.add_offer(sku, name, brand, price)  #отправляю в функцию для сбора данных в XML файл

        elif min_limit < competitor_price < max_limit:
            logger.info("Демпинг конкурента!")
            price = competitor_price - self.dumpingValue  #отправляю в функцию для сбора данных в XML файл
            self.add_offer(sku, name, brand, price)
    
    #Не срабатывает следующий блок кода!!!
    else:
        price = competitor_price - self.dumpingValue   #отправляю в функцию для сбора данных в XML файл
        logger.info("лимиты не найдены, демпинг цены...")
        self.add_offer(sku, name, brand, price)
        
else:
    price = int(r['offers'][0]['price'])
    logger.warning("Товар: " + str(sku) + " - нет конкурента")
    self.add_offer(sku, name, brand, price)  #отправляю в функцию для сбора данных в XML файл
```

Comment: Раз не работает `else` значит работает `if`.

Comment: if и elif работают когда sku находится в БД, а если его нет, то должно сработать else. Вот как раз оно и не работает )

Comment: `elif min_limit < competitor_price < max_limit:` а в питоне так можно? Или это всё-таки неправильная проверка?

Comment: @AlexeyTen можно, оно работает. Вопрос в другом ...

Comment: Таки непонятно в чём вопрос. Если мы не попадаем в `else` значит условие `check_sku == sku` выполнилось. Ну либо не выполнилось условие `competitor != self.StoreName` и тогда тоже непонятно в чём вопрос.

Comment: вопрос - почему не срабатывает else, если НЕ выполняется условие "if check_sku == sku:" ?

Comment: пробовал также через try-except - такой же результат.

Comment: 'Не срабатывает следующий блок кода!!!" свазан со if check_sku == sku: ?

Comment: @СергейШашко Да, а что ? )

Comment: check_sku = sku = 12345678 всегда, по этому  и не срабатывает else.

Comment: @СергейШашко так это же пример! )) в комментариях я указал. Данные берутся из БД, соответственно я проверяю есть ли данные по конкретному SKU (артикулу товара), если в БД пусто, то как раз  блок ELSE должен сработать

Comment: Что значить пусто?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136283/discussion-between-yessey-and--).